# Autocomplete dropdown in codeigniter doesn't works

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm still new using jquery in codeigniter so i hope you can gladly help me.
I want to create autocomplete dropdown where when one option of autocomplete is selected, it will show other related fields.
The output become like this, there's no value to display 
[image]

And this is my codes :
**Model**

```
function search_mtk($kode_mtk){
    $this->db->like('kode_mtk', $kode_mtk , 'both');
    $this->db->order_by('kode_mtk', 'ASC');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    return $this->db->get('m_mata_kuliah')->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_mtk(){  
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result = $this->kit_model->search_mtk($_GET['term']);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
        foreach ($result as $row)
            $arr_result[] = array(
                'kode'  => $row->kode_mtk,
                'nama'  => $row->nama_mtk,
            );
            echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#kode_mtk" ).autocomplete({
  source: "<?php echo base_url('fak/kit/get_mtk/?');?>",
   
   select: function (event, ui) {
    $('[name="kode_mtk"]').val(ui.item.kode); 
    $('[name="nama_mtk"]').val(ui.item.nama); 
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart('fak/kit/file_data');?>               
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="program">Kode Matakuliah <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_mtk" name="kode_mtk" placeholder="Type course code" />
       </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="program">Nama Matakuliah<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_mtk" placeholder="Type course name" />
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems working fine but the label value not showing in the drop-down. just add `value` and `label` key value in the array to check its working or not.

Your code should be like below

```
$arr_result[] = array(
  'kode'  => $row->kode_mtk,
  'nama'  => $row->nama_mtk,
  'value' => $row->nama_mtk,
  'label' => $row->nama_mtk,
);
```

also, add the following call back function inside autocomplete jquery function

```
$( "#kode_mtk" ).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url('fak/kit/get_mtk/?');?>",        
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('[name="kode_mtk"]').val(ui.item.kode); 
            $('[name="nama_mtk"]').val(ui.item.nama); 
        },
        response: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.content.length === 0){
                console.log('No results loaded!');
            }else{
                console.log('success!');
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Anfath Hifans now my results has been loaded as i expected..